# Drupal CSS is not loading after server move

Tags: 6, theming

After moving the server, my CSS files don't work. When I open them in a browser, an error shows up:

> SmartOptimizer Error: Could not create cache file(cache/so_11966173eab0271ad5607eadd11bf298.css.gz).

I have [SmartOptimizer](http://farhadi.ir/projects/smartoptimizer/) Installed, and I don't know if I need to change the settings.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really sound like a Drupal-specific question. That link doesn't even point to a Drupal contrib module.. Have you tried running through the install instructions again?

If you haven't "SmartOptimizer needs write access to smartoptimzer/cache folder. Make sure it's writable." looks pretty telling.

Comment: Thanks, Ues I tried, and I changeg folder permission. no difference.

Comment: Did you also check that the .htaccess came across in the migration?

Comment: Yes I did, In the source server home directory = /home/user and web directory = /home/user/public_html but in the destination server home and web directories are /var/www/html. does it help?

Comment: I thing It's better to remove it.